# Object comparison shorthand

Tags: javascript

In this object, is there a way to write short code which still sticking object style? Note sometime there could be a set of 3,4,5,6,7 questions and the code is a 8 questions.

I rather not using array solutions since I have a large collection of objects.

```
if(item[index].check=="agree") {
    if(item[index+1].check=="yes"
        &&item[index+2].check=="yes"
        &&item[index+3].check=="yes"
        &&item[index+4].check=="yes"
        &&item[index+5].check=="yes"
        &&item[index+6].check=="yes"
        &&item[index+7].check=="no"){
    ...
    totalqns=8
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a [loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have seems fine, but here's a somewhat shorter way, using a map and a loop

```
var map = ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"];
var all = item.every(function(key, index) {
    return key.check === map[index];
});

if ( all ) // do stuff
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/97hxbyy0/37/)

Comment: But the last property (in the example `item[index+7]`) has to be "no". Your example code check if all properties are "yes".

Comment: Bear in mind it should look for the `check` property of what could be an array. (the question is ridiculously unclear)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say so. You could do this:

```
var bool = true;
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  if (item[index+i] !== 'yes') {
    bool = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (bool && item[index+7] !== 'no') {
  bool = false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As it is an *Array-like* of *Strings* we can use `slice` and `join`,

```
var item = ["foo", "agree", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "bar"],
    index = 1;
if (Array.prototype.slice.call(item, index + 1, index + 7 + 1).join('') === 'yesyesyesyesyesyesno') {
    // pass
}
```

Consider that this may fail if you have things other than `"yes"` and `"no"`, e.g. if there are values like `""` and `"yesyes"` then you can't distinguish `"" + "yesyes"` from `"yes" + "yes"` or `"" + "" + "yes"` from `"yes" + "" + ""` this way

---

You have a lots of options if you want to compare *Arrays* though

```
mousetrap: do { // could use labelled `if (true)` instead of labelled `do..while (false)`
    var i, expect = ["yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"];
    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        if (item[index + i + 1] !== expect[i])
            break mousetrap; // but not sure of cross-browser `break` support in `if`s
    // pass
} while (false);
```

---

*Also not sure about cross-browser `foo: {expr; break foo;}` support, the `do..while` shouldn't throw any errors.*

Comment: Why are you doing `Array.prototype.slice.call`?

Comment: @torazaburo was not assuming `item` is an _Array_, so was not assuming `item.slice` exists

Comment: But you just defined `item` and it is very much an array.

Comment: @torazaburo OP didn't define `item`, my definition was just for the example, can't assume OP's `item` is defined the same way

Comment: While there are "lots of options if you want to compare Arrays", you've chosen a particularly unclear and non-idiomatic way of doing so.  A labeled break and `do ... while (false)`?